# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when returning link to facebook profile picture

Tags: facebook, api, token

im trying to return the profile picture of a user with the facebook api, but i get an error in chrome about the link.
here is the code

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                    if(response.status=="connected"){
                    var token=response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    console.log(token);
                    FB.api('me/picture?type=square',function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        });

                    }else{
                        FB.login(function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            },{scope:"email"});
                    }
                    });
                });
```

and the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL         275226_100002726490078_140247_q.jpg:1
```

why is this happening? i dont even know where to start looking for a solution, because i dont know where this error is even coming from.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? With `FB.api('me/picture?type=square'` are you trying to get the image itself or the link to the image?

Comment: @jBit the link, thats what it returns

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a call to https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=square will return image data and the `FB.api` expects JSON.

For the 50×50 square version of the profile picture, you can get the url from  `/me?fields=picture&type=square`:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=picture&type=square',function(response){
    console.log(response.picture);
});
```

- `/me?fields=picture&type=square` - 50×50
- `/me?fields=picture&type=small` - 50 pixels wide, variable height
- `/me?fields=picture&type=large` - about 200 pixels wide, variable height

Comment: get the link to the profile picture, in the api documentation it sais that the request for the picture object will return a valid url to that image.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: A call to an id of a photo object will return a url for the image. However you are try to access the `picture` connection of a user object which will perform `HTTP 302 redirect to URL of the user's profile picture.` - see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This should give you what you want.